# Update app from WP7 to WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I have a problem,

I have WP7 an app in store, which is already installed on Windows Phone 7 and 8 devices. Now I want to add WP8 app version. So in dashboard I click "add new", and selecting new .xap file which is dedicated to WP8. Finally I have two .xap files dedicated to WP7 and WP8.

But my question is: What will happen with the user who has Windows Phone 8 device and some time ago already installed application with WP7 version ?

a) is his app (which is currently WP7)will be automatically updated to WP8

b) nothing will be happen

c) something else (and what)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users on a Windows phone 8 OS handset will get an app upgrade request if their phone is configured for manual app upgrades. Should they accept, the app will be upgraded to the WP8 XAP version you have uploaded. Obviously, users who have opted for the automatic app updates will also be upgraded to the WP8 XAP version.

Any users on WP7 handsets will stay on the WP7 XAP version.

see the examples illustrated on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj631569%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure for that? I checked this on my beta app and no update occured on WP8 device. Additionally on link you sent, there is no information about automatic update. Can you give me some advice or any other ideas why update should occur?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure having done this several times. The example in the link above relating to your scenario is in the "Example app 2" section. Not sure about Beta apps, probably best to raise a support ticket in dev center, their documentation says it should notify beta testers about an update, see "Updating the beta app" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I have additional question. If during this upgrade data saved in IsolatedStorage will preserved or cleared?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442301%28v=vs.105%29.aspx which is applicable to WP7.1, the isolated storage content is preserved. The documentation on here also confirms the same thing for WP8 to WP8.1 (WinRT) https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642081%28v=vs.105%29.aspx I would approach with caution though if the data is that important. Maybe publish the updated app as a hidden app and test this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can always run WP7 application in WP8 devices where as you'll not be able to do the other way around. So you've got two options:

- To have two different apps for WP7 & WP8
- To update your WP7 app to WP8 (which is ideally a single app)

I would suggest the last one, as most of the users have already moved into WP8 it's better if you can target that range of customers.

Answering to your question it'll not automatically update your WP7 application to WP8. So the answer would be nothing would happen, but the user will not be able to use the app as it's not compatible till you release the updated version.

Comment: What do you mean saying that "user will not be able to use the app as it's not compatible till you release the updated version." ? So if I add new .xap file supporting windows phone 8 with higher version number than WP7 app, then everything will working well, and the app will automatically update ?

Comment: kulasanger where you get that information? Can you give me same link? Your answer is the opposite of FunksMaName answer, are you convinced for your answer?

Comment: @Kulasanger. Where you get that info that no update will occur on Windows Phone 8 device and that user won't be able to use the app?

Comment: I couldn't remember the exact place, but as far I can remember it was the case. I didn't read anything after you posted, and then came back and answered here, I answered with what i knew already.